# How to implement registration for the users from outside of LDAP directory in IBM Connections 3.0.1?

Tags: oauth, ldap, oauth-2.0, ibm-connections

Lets consider the deployment of IBM Connections 3.0.1 based on:

> - TDI 7
> - DB2 9.7.2
> - WebSphere Server Network Deployment V7.0
> - IBM HTTP Server 7.0.0.11

It is connected with the Active Directory which is used to authenticate the users. I would like to expand the abilities of Connections, by introducing registration of the users who are not present in the LDAP. 
Is it possible to do that? If so is it possible to use OAuth for that task? 
Documentation specifies OAuth support for the Connections 4, but it doesn't say anything about 3.x versions. If 3.x versions are not capable of using OAuth, please elaborate on implementing the following feature in Connections 4.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth support in Connections 4 is used to access Connections data from the outside world. One example would be Domino 9 Social Edition, using Embedded Experience and Updates widgets for Notes and iNotes. Configuration of these widgets requires OAuth keys to be generated by Connections and entered to the proxy setting for these widgets. In this way Notes and iNotes users can access content from Connections.

At this moment there is a demand from Connections users to allow access to Connections from outside of their organizations. However this issue is not solved yet. In the Greenhouse Connections community you will find several ideas about it in the ideation blog. So far none of those ideas are marked as granted. However there's still hope to see it implemented in 4.5, which is expected to be out in March 2013. Also IBM makes possible for externals to access Connections in their IBM Customer Experience Suite, where you can create a community, accessible for externals. I personally have no experience with this product but have seen IBM demo from IBM Connect 2012. I plan to have POC with it when I get enough computing power to install the suite.